# Can you put a <div> inside a <div>?

Tags: html

As an exercise, I am building a website for a non-profit group and I am encountering a weird, to me at least, issue.

On my main page I have a white box floating in a dark blue background. This box holds my main content. I have the main image, the logo, the sidebar, the text. I am trying to put in another box for upcoming news and events. I was hoping to put in a screenshot of my page for reference, but I don't have enough reputation points. Sorry...

The main area is a div and I was trying to put in another  for my news, but I can't figure out how to make it work. The main box is 900px, and there is the header, the sidebar, the image. Under the image I am pretty much trying to put in two columns inside this box.

Is this at all possible?

I looked everywhere, I looked in CSS-Tricks, I looked in W3Schools Online, I looked here, but I don't see anything that helps me figure out how to make this happen, or even if it is possible. I Googled it, I Yahoo'd it, no luck. I am sure it has to be possible, I just don't know how.

Comment: Try using jsfiddle.net to give us a basic example of what you have so far.

Comment: Have you really never seen a web site with two columns?

Comment: I have, and I have been able to put in columns, but the design I am using is making it harder.

Comment: Shredder, if you look at this link:  http://www.langokidsirvine.com/?gclid=CKLN98W7zroCFWJBQgoda1cAlA  it's similar to what I have. I have a colored background, and a box floating inside it. They pretty much have three columns inside the box, and I am trying to do something similar. The only real difference is that I have a large image below the header and links bar. Under all of the I am trying to make my two columns. I just can't figure out how they did that.

Comment: Jace, my HTML or my CSS? Or both? I should warn you, they are both probably a mess

Comment: Show *your* code. This is really basic stuff, but there could be a thousand reasons why *your* code doesn't work, there's no way to know without seeing it. If you want to see how someone else has done it, right click -> view source.

Comment: I opened up a jsfiddle account. I really hope I did it right...http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=lGrjw8v1AS

Answer (score 6):

So you are trying to put a div in a div? For what i understand from your post this can be done like this:

```
<div id='main_div'>
  <div id='news'> ... </div>
</div>
```

if you place some more information like a 'live' example or jsfiddle.net we can help you out better.

Comment: The instant downvote is ridiculous, but if I were you, I wouldn't even attempt to answer a question until it has been edited with more detail.

Comment: This is basically a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I hope I did this right, I just opened up a jsfiddle account. http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=lGrjw8v1AS

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much for this! I just tried it out and it iw working perfectly! I've been trying to figure this out the last day or two, so you have no idea how happy I am. Thanks again!

Comment: @user2957701 if it helped you, you can accept the question. :) Good luck with your website.

Comment: @Juhana basically my ''comment'' was the answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Preface

I list flow I followed to find this particular answer as an example of how to read the docs to answer this particular question and a general help to those who arrive here with this question. The whole thing is a practice in "teaching others to fish" for answers in the docs. Particular help walks a reader through navigating the docs in this case.

General help argues for the utilization of the docs to answer one's own questions. Wouldn't you, the reader, rather be able to find your own answers anytime of the day or night instead of waiting for serendipity and the efforts of others to answer every question that arises? I know I do.

## Particular Help

1. A google search for "html5 spec" revealed html5 docs located [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/).
2. From these docs, a text-search for "div" revealed a [link to the relevant section.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element)
3. In the linked listing of contents directly below the title was

   - ```
     [Contexts in which this element can be used:]
          Where [flow content] is expected.
     ```
4. "Flow content" linked to a list of elements that are flow content.
5. Div, span, and p elements are listed here.
6. A div containing a p(aragraph) was seen in the code example from the div section
7. A div can go anywhere a p can go because they are both flow content.
8. A div is permissible in any context allowing flow control.
9. Hence, a div can contain a div.

## General Help

### Read the docs.

Docs don't bite. That is, well written docs don't bite. Rather, docs empower their readers with a mastery of the subject documented. This is true whether the subject is a language or a piece of hardware.

Many docs are structured text. Textual data grants searchability. Structure eases perusal and interpretation.

#### Docs often

- exemplify use-patterns used by experts(ie, how to accomplish common tasks cleverly),
- specify capabilities built by the creator of the subject(eg, the designers of a language), and
- help readers avoid problems not yet encountered.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a div inside an div but once you do that you can only put block elements (like divs) inside the first div. And if you put an inline element inside an div only inline elements can go inside the div. I am not sure as to what extent an block element is still considered an block element because you can make a lot of changes using css.

```
<h1>Header</h1>
<div style="float: left"><p>box 1 float left</p></div>
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 20px;"><p>Float Left box 2</p></div>
<div style="float: left; margin-left: 20px;"><p>Float Left box 3</p></div>
<h1 style="clear: both">Footer</h1>
```

I think what you are trying to do is what I have coded above. I use a simple one column page on my personal site. I am not sure why I have 3 floats instead of two but it works anyway.